# how use rtsp in android media player with wowza?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, wowza

I want to play mp4 in my android app, but when I set my file to a URL in the server the app pushes the message "cannot play this video"

Sometimes I had anerror in eclipse "app can not find this directory"

And I sometimes had this error "status: RTSP/1.0 401 unauthorized"

Here's the code I'm using to set the url:

```
objItem.setVideoUrl("rtsp://ipserver:1935/live/mp4:sample.mp4");
```

How can I get this to play properly?

Answer (score 1):

after an hour spent about this i found that answer
i forgot to set "none" in this this node value

```
            <PublishMethod>digest</PublishMethod>
            <PlayMethod>none</PlayMethod>
```